# If / then type statement required in JSON format

Tags: json, shopify, zapier

I have some working JSON code that can update inventory in a Shopify store via Webhooks by Zapier (Custom Request). I need to add some statements equivalent to if/then/else to make it so that the inventory is updated only when the inventory_item_id is NOT equal to 1.

```
{
  "location_id": 123455677,
  "inventory_item_id": 112346873458,
  "disconnect_if_necessary": true,
  "available": 2
}
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your JSON-related code? Adding properties conditionally in JS or Python is very simple, but it can't be done _directly_ in JSON. You presumably have code that generates that json? that would be the place to add it.

Comment: Thanks, if I remember I think I ended up doing it just using typical if statements but maybe I had to change to a javascript code block in zapier instead of doing it in the webhook block. But anyway, this is ancient history now and I'm way past it. Cheers.